# How to detect enter and exit streetView in Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Is there a way to detect when a user enters and exits StreetView in Google Maps under API v3?

I want to trigger an existing 'Hide Menu' function when the user enters StreetView (as the menu isn't relevant) and then re-show the menu when they exit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Observe the `visible_changed`-event of the streetView, the `visible`-property will be `true` or `false` (open or closed)

```js
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5498783, 13.425209),
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map.getStreetView(),'visible_changed',function(){
           alert('streetview is ' +(this.getVisible()?'open':'closed'));
        });
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
      html,body,#map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the visible_changed event listener and also add a doAlert() function. This would enable the street view to make an alert on entry for the street view and also while exitting the street view.